# Generating a QCloseEvent won't close QMainWindow

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I'm trying to do something quite simple: add a menu bar with an `Exit` action that will close a `QMainWindow` when it is selected. However, when I actually click `Exit`, it doesn't close the application. A SSCCE:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

import sys

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.menu_bar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
        menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu('File')

        exit_action = QtGui.QAction('Exit', self)
        exit_action.triggered.connect(lambda:
            self.closeEvent(QtGui.QCloseEvent()))
        menu.addAction(exit_action)
        self.setMenuBar(self.menu_bar)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print('Calling')
        print('event: {0}'.format(event))
        event.accept()


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Window()
form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What is really confusing me is that when I click `Exit` from the `File` menu, I get the following output:

> Calling
>
> event: <PyQt4.QtGui.QCloseEvent object at 0x024B7348>

and the application does not exit.

If I click the top-right corner `X`, I get the same thing (down to the same memory address for the event object):

> Calling
>
> event: <PyQt4.QtGui.QCloseEvent object at 0x024B7348>

and the application *does* exit.

This is on Windows 7 64-bit, Python 2.7.2, PyQt 4.8.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document [says](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcloseevent.html),

> The **QCloseEvent** class contains parameters that describe a close event.
>
> Close events are sent to widgets that the user wants to close, usually
>   by choosing "Close" from the window menu, or by clicking the X title
>   bar button. They are also sent when you call **QWidget.close()** to close
>   a widget programmatically.

Your can call directly with signal close not by `QCloseEvent`, please call `self.close()`.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

import sys

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.menu_bar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
        menu = self.menu_bar.addMenu('File')

        exit_action = QtGui.QAction('Exit', self)
        exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)
        menu.addAction(exit_action)
        self.setMenuBar(self.menu_bar)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print('Calling')
        print('event: {0}'.format(event))
        event.accept()


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Window()
form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

The close event doesn't actually make the window close, it's just triggered when the window *is already closing*. To actually make the window close, you need to call `self.close()`, which will have the side effect of triggering a `QCloseEvent`. So simply use this:

```
 exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)
```

The [documentation of `close`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#close) describes the interaction between `close` and `closeEvent`:

> **bool QWidget.close (self)**
>
> This method is also a Qt slot with the C++ signature bool close().
>
> Closes this widget. Returns true if the widget was closed; otherwise
>   returns false.
>
> **First it sends the widget a QCloseEvent. The widget is hidden if it
>   accepts the close event. If it ignores the event, nothing happens. The
>   default implementation of QWidget.closeEvent() accepts the close
>   event.**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes more sense now.