# C++ Qt QCloseEvent doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a message which appears in a new window when the user presses the exit button. Therefor I create a QCloseEvent, but the MainWindow actually doesn't close at all. What am I doing wrong?

Mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    //Constructor
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

    //Destructor
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void closeMainWindow();

private:
    QCloseEvent *event;
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::closeMainWindow(){

    event = new QCloseEvent();
    QMessageBox::StandardButton answer = QMessageBox::question(
                this,
                tr("Close the Window"),
                tr("Do you want to close the window?"),
                QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);

    if(answer == QMessageBox::Yes){
        event->accept();
    }
    else
        event->ignore();
}
```

Comment: Your mistake is next: you have created an event, but you didn't send it.

Answer (score 4):

You must implement [closeEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#closeEvent) function of mainwindow!

e.g

```
void MyMainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    QMessageBox::StandardButton answer = QMessageBox::question(
                this,
                tr("Close the Window"),
                tr("Do you want to close the window?"),
                QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);

    if(answer == QMessageBox::Yes){
        event->accept();
    }
    else
        event->ignore();
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you.. But still got an answer. I want to use an connect command, so I want to call the closeEvent, when the user clicks on a button. 

Therefore I wrote this code:

``QObject::connect(exit, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), MainWindow, SLOT(closeEvent()));``

But the compiler says, that he can't find the closeEvent. I think it is, because the closeEvent is an protected function, but it has to be an public slots function, right?

Comment: @Blacktiger800 yes, you need to use a `close` slot. Please, read Qt documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing close() function

```
if(answer == QMessageBox::Yes)
{
  event->accept();
  close();
}
```

or override closeEvent() function of MainWindow

Refer below link:
[Generating a QCloseEvent won't close QMainWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717048/generating-a-qcloseevent-wont-close-qmainwindow)